# Removing a subset of a dict from within a list

Tags: python, list, containers

This is really only easy to explain with an example, so to remove the intersection of a list from within a dict I usually do something like this:

```
a = {1:'', 2:'', 3:'', 4:''}
exclusion = [3, 4, 5]

# have to build up a new list or the iteration breaks
toRemove = []
for var in a.iterkeys():
    if var in exclusion:
        toRemove.append(var)

for var in toRemove:
    del a[var]
```

This might seem like an unusual example, but it's surprising the number of times I've had to do something like this. Doing this with sets would be much nicer, but I clearly want to retain the 'values' for the dict.

This method is annoying because it requires two loops and an extra array. Is there a cleaner and more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider [dict.pop](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```
for key in exclusion:
     a.pop(key, None)
```

The `None` keeps pop from raising an exception when `key` isn't a key.

Comment: Oh, this is far better than my answer.

Comment: nice tip, dict.pop is oft-forgotten.

Comment: You can use any value instead of None: deleted = [d.pop(k,0) for k in exclusion]

Comment: It's true. None seemed cheap and easy and very... Noneish. I figured it would feel right in any circumstances, where 0 might feel weird in a string context or "" in a numeric one.

Comment: This is really nice. Much cleaner. I would question whether there would be a more efficient way if the list of exclusions was significantly larger than the dict, rather than iterating through the entire list?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = dict((key,value) for (key,value) in a.iteritems() if key not in exclusion)
```

Comment: This solution avoids explicit loops, which is good, but it reconstructs the dictionary from scratch, which is bad. Maybe dictionaries should steal some methods from sets?

Comment: I'm never sure how much benefit you get from avoid loops and so staying in the C code.  I guess it will all depend on how big your dict is and how much of it you're removed.  I think Blair's answer would be more efficient for large dicts but I've have to test it to be sure.

Comment: Funny, removing half of the keys from a 200k dict (a[i]=i for i in range(200k)) in a loop is only about 30% slower on my machine than copying the dict.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `keys` method, instead of `iterkeys`? That way you can do it in one loop because it returns a list, not an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your exclusion list to a set, then just use intersection to get the overlap.

```
exclusion = set([3, 4, 5])

for key in exclusion.intersection(a):
    del a[key]
```